# Skip Item in Dataflow TransformBlock

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

[TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx) provides a `TransformBlock` for transforming input, e.g.:

```
var tb = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i => i * 2);
```

Is it possible to not output some of the input, e.g. if the input fails some validation test?

```
var tb = new TransformBlock<InputType, OutputType>(i =>
{
    if (!ValidateInput(i))
    {
        // Do something to not output anything for this input
    }
    // Normal output
}
```

If that is not possible, what would be the best pattern to achieve that end?
Something like the following?

```
BufferBlock<OutputType> output = new BufferBlock<OutputType>();

var ab = new ActionBlock<InputType>(i =>
{
    if (ValidateInput(i)) 
    {
        output.Post(MyTransform(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are several options on how to do this:

1. Use `TransformManyBlock` as Jon suggested and return a collection containing 1 or 0 items.
2. Use `TransformBlock` with some special value representing “no value” (e.g. `null`) and then use a `LinkTo()` with filter to remove those. You also have to link the `TransformBlock` to null block ([`DataflowBlock.NullTarget<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462765.aspx)) without a filter, to drain the special values.
3. I would consider this something of a hack, but you can also use the `Task`-based constructor of `TransformBlock`: use `Task.FromResult()` when you want to return something and `null` when you don't.  For example:

   ```
   new TransformBlock<int, int>(i => i % 2 == 0 ? Task.FromResult(i * 2) : null)
   ```

Answer (score 13):

I haven't used DataFlow myself, but I *think* you could use a [`TransformManyBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194784.aspx), and just make each step return either an empty collection or a single item.

```
var tmb = new TransformManyBlock<InputType, OutputType>(i =>
{
    if (!ValidateInput(i))
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<OutputType>();
    }
    ...
    // Or return new[] { outputValue };
    return Enumerable.Repeat(outputValue, 1);
});
```

You could even potentially generalize this to a `FilterBlock<T>` which *just* has a filter predicate, and passes appropriate matches through (just like `Where` in LINQ). You could initially implement this using `TransformManyBlock` as above, but then make it more efficient later.

Answer (score 9):

A little bit old question, want to add some experience here: you can introduce a [`BufferBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414.aspx) instead of [`ActionBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx) for your data, and use [`LinkTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194832.aspx) extension method with condition predicate, so the valid values will proceed to the [`TransformBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194782.aspx), and invalid ones will be ignored. For discarding them you can simply use [`NullTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462765.aspx) block, which simply ignores the data it receives. So the final code could look like this:

```
var input = new BufferBlock<int>();
var tb = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i => i * 2);
var output = new BufferBlock<int>();

// valid integers will pass to the transform
input.LinkTo(tb, i => ValidateInput(i));

// not valid will be discarded
input.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<int>());

// transformed data will come to the output
tb.LinkTo(output);
```

Also linking could be adjusted with some [`DataflowLinkOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions.aspx) with [other `LinkTo` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462705.aspx).

Comment: This is essentially option (2) in svick's answer.

Comment: @GordonBean with added direct link between the blocks